TV show from 90s with child who stopped time for others by clapping?
There was a girl living in a house with her parents. Any time the girl clapped her hands, time stood still and everything held on. The only one who was able to move was the girl. When she clapped her hands again, time went on.
I´m not sure but I think the show was on Nickelodeon.

The show you're looking might be Out of this World.
"Evie's main power is the ability to freeze time on Earth by joining two fingers, allowing her to maneuver herself or objects to alter the course of events on Earth. When she claps her hands together, time resumes as normal. She can also "unfreeze" individuals by touching them while time is frozen."
Wikipedia
The show was from 1987 to 1991 which also seems to fit pretty well.

yep thats what I was looking for. thx
